# getting 403 error on watch request on gmail API php

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am trying to make watch request to gmail API but getting 403 error every time :- Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/projectId/topics/topic : User not authorized to perform this action.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/opt/lampp/htdocs/gmail-api/client_secret.json');
$client->setScopes(array("https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"));
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$watchreq = new Google_Service_Gmail_WatchRequest();
$watchreq->setLabelIds(array('INBOX'));
$watchreq->setTopicName('projects/Id/topics/tid');
$msg = $service->users->watch('me', $watchreq);
```

Comment: When it pops up and asks you to authenticate what permissions is it requesting?

Comment: GmailPushApi would like to:

1.Read, send, delete, and manage your email
Click for more information
More info
2.View your emails messages and settings
Click for more information
More info
3.View and modify but not delete your email
Click for more information
More info
4. Manage drafts and send emails
Click for more information
More info
5.View and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform services
6.View and manage Pub/Sub topics and subscriptions
--------I am able to read gmail msg and create and publish topic individualy.getting error on Watch request only.

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645610/1576958