# gmail.users.watch fails to send test message to PubSub with a DwD service account

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to setup gmail.users.watch but am getting a 403 error:

`Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/project-id/topics/topic-id : User not authorized to perform this action.`

Authentication is working using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` approach and the downloaded credentials json file.

The following code works correctly which supports my hypothesis that the authentication is generally working:

```
const pubsub = PubSub();
const topic = pubsub.topic('topic-id');
const subscription = pubsub.subscription('subscription-id');
topic.exists()
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return subscription.exists();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return subscription.pull()
  })
  .then(data => {
    data[1].receivedMessages.forEach(d => console.log(d));
    return topic.publish('Hello, world!');
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

No errors from that code. However the following code throws the 403 error described above:

```
const authParams = {
  subject: userId,
  scopes: [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub'
  ]
};

gauth.getAuth(authParams)
  .then(authClient => {
    const params = {
      auth: authClient,
      userId: 'me',
      resource: {
        topicName: <topic-id>
      }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gmail.users.watch(params, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

`gauth.getAuth` is a simple wrapper around `getApplicationDefault`[Google Auth Library for Node.js](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs).

The G Suite domain security Client Access is configured with the Client ID of the service account against the scopes needed: 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub`, `https://mail.google.com/`

As the native cloud pub/sub stuff works I think the service account has all of the correct permissions configured on the console so I'm a bit at a loss as to why the gmail call is failing.

UPDATE:
Service Account has the following permissions on Google Cloud Console:

Project: (Does it need more than this for the gmail stuff?)

- Service Account Actor
- PubSub Admin

Topic:

- Owner

Subscription:

- Owner

When making the gmail call the service account is delegating to a 'subject'. I've added permissions for that subject userId to the Google Cloud Console:

Project:

- Owner

Topic:

- Owner

Subscription:

- Owner

Comment: I think this has something to do with [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) roles. Go to Google Dev Console and set the service account role to admin or owner - users roles with top level authority.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've already done that. The service account has PubSub Admin and Service Account Actor at the project level.

Comment: It also has owner on the topic and subscription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add permissions so messages can be publish to your subscription.

Go to Google Cloud console, select the subscription and then Permissions.
In the Add members section, type *allAuthenticatedUsers*, select the *Pub/Sub publisher role* and click **Add**

Does it help?

Update (2017/05/09):

I'm editing my answer in order to be more accurate about what's needed.

According to the [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) (see the ***Grant publish rights on your topic*** section):

- the permission needs to be set at the topic level
- the member is: ***serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com***
- the role is: ***Pub/Sub Publisher***

Comment: The service account is added as Owner on the Subscription and Topic, would that not include publishing privileges?

Comment: I was getting the same error and adding allAuthenticatedUsers with Pub/Sub publisher fixed the issue. According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access_control), owner role should work.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a go when I get to the office!

Comment: `allAuthenticatedUsers` makes it accessible to public. Go with the recommended `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`.
For this, go to Add Member(in permissions tab) and type in `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` in the new member input, then select role of Pub/Sub Publisher and then save it.