# Guzzle Sends HTTP request to Gmail API, 'Invalid resource type: object'

Tags: php, gmail-api, guzzle, google-client

I use Guzzle to send HTTP request to [Gmail API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

it throws Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid resource type: object' 
It looks like I fed `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request()` Class mistakenly?

```
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=sample.json');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    // returns a Guzzle HTTP Client
    $httpClient = $client->authorize();
    $data = new stdClass; 
    $data-> topicName ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
    $data-> labelIds = ["INBOX"];
    $data-> labelFilterAction = 'include';
    $request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST','https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/post@sample.com/watch',['Content-type'=>'application/json'],$data);
    $response = $httpClient->send($request);
    var_dump($response);

//------------output----------------------
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid resource type: object'
```

Thanks to Andrew Nolan and Denis Solakovic, now `$request` seems in right format.

Here is the update:
I am using a service account credential to watch new mail, does anyone know where I did wrong ? Many thanks.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=sample.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
// returns a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$data = new stdClass; 
$data-> topicName ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
$data-> labelIds = ["INBOX"];
$data-> labelFilterAction = 'include';
$data = json_encode((array)$data);
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/post@sample.com/watch',["Content-type" =>"application/json"],$data);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
echo ($response->getBody());

//--------------output---------------------
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "failedPrecondition", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }
```

Comment: you need to json_encode your data. You are sending GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request an object but it is expecting json.

Comment: As mentioned by @AndrewNolan you are sending a request with header that states application/json, so you should convert your $request object to JSON:
`$json = json_encode( (array)$request );`

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it now, I missed this step:

> you need to grant publish privileges to
>
> **serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com** at  [Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console permissions interface](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/cloudpubsub/topicList)

and then the code **by Sending direct HTTP request with Guzzle:**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('xxxx-b2838442f7ad.json'); // downloaded json file.
$client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"));
$user_to_impersonate = 'post@sample.com'; //very important
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate); //important
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$data = new stdClass; 
$data-> topicName ='projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic';   
$data-> labelIds = ["INBOX"];
$data-> labelFilterAction = 'include';
$data = json_encode($data);
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/post@sample.com/watch',["Content-type" =>"application/json"],$data);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
echo($response->getBody());


// ------------------output-----------------------------------
    { "historyId": "31325", "expiration": "1496503166524" }
```

or the code by **Gmail Classes**-this is more difficult, you need to look into *`User.php`* and *`WatchRequest.php`*, if not [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472845/getting-403-error-on-watch-request-on-gmail-api-php), there was no chance for an amateur like me:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('xxxx-b2838442f7ad.json'); // downloaded json file.
$client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"));
$user_to_impersonate = 'post@sample.com'; //very important
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate); //important
$watchreq = new Google_Service_Gmail_WatchRequest;
$watchreq->setLabelIds(array('INBOX'));
$watchreq->setTopicName('projects/sample.com:sample/topics/topic');
$watchreq->setLabelFilterAction('include');
$gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$response =$gmailService->users->watch('me', $watchreq);
echo($response->expiration)."<br/>";
echo($response->historyId);

//---------------------output--------------------------

1496505109513
31331
```